# event message is not recognized

Tags: python, discord, bots

i'm trying to make a discord bot and I want to add functionality that handles events like ?help, ?creator etc. I want to send a message if the command after ? is not recognised. This is my code:

````
import os
import discord

client = discord.Client()
unrecogcommand = "I don't recognize this command do **?help** for the list of the available 
commands :3"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith('?'):
    if message.content.startswith('?ownerfavOP'):
      await message.channel.send("The server Owner really love Kaikai Kitan 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1P-9IspBus :3")

    if message.content.startswith('?creator'):
      await message.channel.send("PashPash#7668 is the username of the creator and have a yt 
channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxJXY07JAsmJBaYf67KKk7Q")

    if message.content.startswith('?help'):
      await message.channel.send("Command available ```?help``` ```ownerfavOP```")

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
````

Comment: its just an else statement after everything in your case

Comment: i tried else but it kinda work but some code is a recognized command but it still sends a urecognized command message

Comment: @Rainygan Use `elif`: `if` => ´elif´ => `else`, that's the typical structure of an if-else statement. Anyways try to avoid `else`.

Comment: or use `elif` instead of every `if` that comes after the first `if`

Comment: @MΛIK can you show me some example?

Comment: the problem with using else in this case is that everything is defined as if statements instead of elif's. So the else will only trigger on a single check. It would always have access to the prior if statements and the comparison would never be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach your `command` like that:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user:
        if message.content.startswith('?'):
            if message.content.startswith('?ownerfavOP'):
                # do something
            elif message.content.startswith('?creator'):
                # do something
            elif message.content.startswith('?help'):
                # do something
            else:
                print("Couldn't found that command.")
```

**Note** that I removed the `return` statment, since the command will automatically return if the `message author` equals the `client user`.

I hope this helps you, sheers!

Comment: in this case, dont forget to add the else statement that shows how to handle anything other than those specific commands. :)

Comment: i see, you removed the if message.content.startswith('?'): thing so it sends the message everytime you send a message but i was able to fix it quickly

Comment: @Rainygan That's correct but I've later added it back into my answer :) Seems like I just was too late to correct my error :D